# react-native material Text input Design not Showing exactly

Tags: react-native

I am following this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-textfield

But, I didn't get the Exact showing that input and When i was enter in Text not Showing in this filed.

Please Find Out my Issue

Here this my Code:

```
<View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>

      <TextField style={{ opacity: 0 , marginLeft: windowSize.width / 1.4, color: 'red' }}
        label='Phone number'
        textColor={'red'}
        value={this.state.userName}
        labelHeight={40}
      disabled={false}
        labelPadding={1}
        Bottom padding= {8}
        labelHeight={32}
        multiline={true}
        blurOnSubmit={true}
  //characterRestriction={10}
onChangeText={(data) => this.setState({ userName: data })}
      />
</View>
```

I want like this showing in given text filed in above link like that...

Comment: Try removing the `opacity: 0`. That would hide anything in the field.

Comment: I tried  this but  it will show only One letter

Comment: try to remove `color: 'red'`

Comment: okay but didn't get it